# Cast enum variants of same underlying type

Tags: casting, rust, variant

Is there a simple way to create an `enum` that provides the ability to coerce or otherwise cast instances from one variant to another, as long as the underlying types match?

For instance, given this enum:

```
enum CanConvert {
    Vec1(Vec<String>),
    Vec2(Vec<String>),
    NotVec(i32),
}
```

I would like to be able to easily convert between the `Vec1` and `Vec2` variants:

```
let v1 = CanConvert::Vec1(["one", "two", "three", "uno", "dos", "tres"]
                          .iter()
                          .map(|&s| s.into())
                          .collect());

let v2 = v1 as CanConvert::Vec2;
```

The code above currently gives the error `not a type`, since enum variants are not (currently) considered types. And even if it compiled, it's not clear how the case where `v1` is the `NotVec` variant should be handled (panic?).

This works, but it's pretty verbose, and this seems like it should be a reasonably common pattern:

```
let v2 = match v1 {
    CanConvert::Vec1(ref underlying) |
    CanConvert::Vec2(ref underlying) => CanConvert::Vec2(underlying.clone()),
    _ => panic!("v1 did not have appropriate underlying type!"),
};
```

So is there a simple way to provide this kind of simple type-transformation between variants where possible? I haven't written any of my own `Deref` coercions, but that seems like it might be what I'm looking for here. (A coercion wrapped in some kind of custom `derive` would be ideal.)

**EDIT:** Note that as far as I can tell, there cannot be any safe way of obtaining a *reference* to the original, with the desired variant type; a full clone is required, because the reference would necessarily have the wrong variant tag. However, it seems like it should be possible to *convert* the original `enum` by simply changing the tag appropriately.

Comment: ...I suppose it's also possible that having multiple variants with the same underlying type isn't really rustic, in which case this whole issue should probably be avoided.

Comment: *and this seems like it should be a reasonably common pattern* — I disagree. The main reason I would use two enum variants with the same wrapped type is *because* they have different meanings. Since they have different meanings, converting from one to the other would usually require some extra processing, which wouldn't be abstractable.

Comment: @Shepmaster But all different types have different meanings, so your argument seems to apply to all forms of type coercion.

Comment: @KyleStrand: Indeed, and you'll note that in Rust said conversions are explicit.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Isn't `var as NewType` explicit?

Comment: @KyleStrand: It is... however as far as I can tell, *it cannot fail*. I think the only `as` conversions which can fail (panic) are integer to integer conversion (in case of underflow/overflow). If I recall correctly there's an issue with the float -> integer conversion (LLVM treats it as undefined behavior when overflow occurs). Otherwise, `as` should just work, whereas in your case it does not. So a more explicit conversion makes it more obvious that there is a potential failure point here... and let you choose, for example, to return a `Result` instead of panicking.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Okay, that makes sense. Permitting such a conversion only when *all* variants have the same underlying data (or no variants have associated data) wouldn't have that problem, but at that point the feature would admittedly be kind of abusing a keyword for very little value.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, since `&T` is an immutable reference, an implementation of `Deref` *cannot* change a type. It can merely point *inside* (in this case, it could point to the underlying `Vec`).

Regarding conversion, `ref` is introducing an inefficiency here as it forces you to `clone`, if you take ownership instead you can simply move the underlying vector:

```
fn to_v2(v: CanConvert) -> CanConvert {
    match v {
        CanConvert::Vec1(u) | CanConvert::Vec2(u) => CanConvert::Vec2(u),
        _ => panic!("Inappropriate type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh, I thought I'd tried that and found that I couldn't move out of `v` while matching on it. Glad to see that I was mistaken.

Comment: This can also be simplified to an `if let`: `let v2 = if let CanConvert::Vec1(underlying) = v1 {  CanConvert::Vec2(underlying)  } else { /* handle unexpected enum variant here */ };